# Stream video from one Pi to a web server on a different Pi, then process video (for motion detection)

Tags: networking, web-server, streaming-video, server, streaming

I would like to stream video from one of my Pi's (192.168.1.3) to a web server that is hosted on a different Pi (192.168.1.4). It's supposed to kind of replicate a cloud video surveillance system. At the moment, I'm using motion to stream the video from a camera on .3 to a server hosted on the same Pi. Motion processes the images and saves motion as mkv files, then I have a Python script that sends those files to my .4 Pi. It's not exactly what I actually want, but it works for the premise of my project outline.

I was wondering how complex it would be to send the RTMP/RTSP to a different IP (.4) and stream it, and also use motion (or maybe OpenCV would be better) on the .4 Pi to process and save the video?

Thanks for any replies.